# Duplicate iframe: Copy head and body from 1 iframe to another

Tags: javascript

Simple question which I can't seem to find an answer of:
I have two iframes on a page and I'd like to copy the content of the first one to the second.
But I can't do it by just copying the url of the first iframe to the second since the containing page is a dynamic one.

This code does do it, but a lot of the page-formatting seems to get lost. And I don't know if it's cross-browser either.

```
iframe2.contentWindow.document.write(iframe1.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML);
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Are they all hosted by the same domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Native JavaScript Solution As Asked For:***

First, to make things simple I created 2 object literals:

```
var iframe1 = {

    doc     : undefined,
    head    : undefined,
    body    : undefined

};

var iframe2 = {

    doc     : undefined,
    head    : undefined,
    body    : undefined

};
```

Next, I put everything under iframe1's `window.onload` handler to make sure it was loaded fully:

```
document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.onload = function() {
```

Then I assigned all of the object literal properties:

```
    iframe1.doc = document.getElementById("iframe1").contentWindow.document;
    iframe1.head = iframe1.doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    iframe1.body = iframe1.doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    iframe2.doc = document.getElementById("iframe2").contentWindow.document;
    iframe2.head = iframe2.doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    iframe2.body = iframe2.doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
```

Next, I needed to create a couple functions `removeNodes()` and `appendNodes()` so that I could re-factor some code that is used for both `<head>` and `<body>` routines.

```
    function removeNodes(node) {

        while (node.firstChild) { 

            console.log("removing: " + node.firstChild.nodeName);
            node.removeChild(node.firstChild); 

        } 
    }
```

and:

```
    function appendNodes(iframe1Node, iframe2Node) {

        var child = iframe1Node.firstChild;
        while (child) { 

        if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) { 

            console.log("appending: " + child.nodeName);

            if (child.nodeName === "SCRIPT") {

                // We need to create the script element the old-fashioned way
                // and append it to the DOM for IE to recognize it.

                var script = iframe2.doc.createElement("script");
                script.type = child.type;
                script.src = child.src;

                iframe2Node.appendChild(script);

            } else { 

                // Otherwise, we append it the regular way. Note that we are
                // using importNode() here. This is the proper way to create                        
                // a copy of a node from an external document that can be 
                // inserted into the current document. For more, visit MDN:
                // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.importNode

                iframe2Node.appendChild(iframe2.doc.importNode(child, true)); 
            } 
        }

        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
```

With those functions created, now all we have to do is make our calls:

```
    console.log("begin removing <head> nodes of iframe2");
    removeNodes(iframe2.head);

    console.log("begin removing <body> nodes of iframe2");  
    removeNodes(iframe2.body);

    console.log("begin appending <head> nodes of iframe1 to iframe2");
    appendNodes(iframe1.head, iframe2.head);

    console.log("begin appending <body> nodes of iframe1 to iframe2");
    appendNodes(iframe1.body, iframe2.body);
```

... and finally, we close off the `window.onload` function:

```
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about without jQuery or such? Is there a simple way then? And yes, they're on the same domain

Comment: @Clox - See my edit. I'm not sure of how or when you are calling this code. If you are calling it on the initial page load of the parent page, you may need to wrap this code in a `setTimeout()` call or a for loop that waits until `iframe1` and `iframe2` aren't `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply (and sorry for my late reply). I tried what you suggested and it seems to have the same effect as what I said i tried in the question. It copies the html but the css-formatting gets lost. I actually just almost solved this by also copying document.head but it fails in ie for some reason (havent looked into why it does) and also, script-elements doesn't seem to get copied. None of the links in the page work because they all rely on javascript with a __doPostBack rather than being normal links. Any solution to this? =)

Comment: @Clox - I've updated my answer. I removed the jQuery solution and totally modified the native JS solution. I have this working in IE9, FF11, and Chrome18. The script file gets added whether it was in the head or the body and executes. I left the `console.log` entries in, so you can test yourself and see the output. My script file that I used had 1 line of `console.log("success");` and I get 2 entries in each browser I mentioned showing that it worked.

Comment: @Clox - I updated my answer again. The underlying code didn't change, but I thought I'd re-factor it to use functions instead of re-using basically the same code in 2 places for both the head and body. Tested this and it still works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I was able to get everything working thanks to you. I did have to do a couple changes though because everything wasn't being duplicated properly. First I simply removed this check: " if (child.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {" so that text-nodes is included as well. And also, since javascript-elements can contain text rather than src I made it duplicate that as well. Maybe your answer should be changed to make these two things work? Thank you =)