# Play singe youtube video in two iframes

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I was wondering whenever it is possible to play 1 single youtube video in two different iframes? I need this for stereo rendering. I can not clone the source iframe into another, because there is a CORS violation regarding the context. Does the youtube player provide any kind of render target functionality? What I need is the following:

- Play and **download** 1 single video
- Display the video in two separate iframes positioned randomly on the screen (we are talking about 1 single frame of video being displayed in 2 render targets or textures)
- I do not want to start the video twice and have some delays
- I do not want to download the video twice to show the same picture 2 times

Does anyone have experience with this?

Kind regards,
Aleš Mohorič

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9930470/duplicate-iframe-copy-head-and-body-from-1-iframe-to-another

Comment: Well, you can do it by creating two [iframe](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) player. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mattkoskela/Whxjx/) on how to make it.